# talking to the umpire after being ejected

Tags: baseball, officiating

Why does the umpire and manager/player keep on argueing after the ejection? Why does the umpire let the manager/player keep on talking to him and remain on the field after being ejected?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the umpire and manager/player keep on argueing after the ejection?

Why does anyone ever argue with a umpire/referee at all? Certainly no official at the professional level is ever going to change their mind because somebody shouted at them. That leaves two possibilities:

- They do it because they're human, and sometimes humans do things which aren't rational, particularly when they're frustrated.
- They think that by shouting at the official, they may cause the official to (subconsciously) favour that team in later decisions, or they may improve their team morale by letting the other players see that someone "is sticking up for them against The Man".

I personally suspect the first of these points is the reason in the vast majority of cases.

> Why does the umpire let the manager/player keep on talking to him and remain on the field after being ejected?

What do you suggest the umpire does in this scenario? Walking away isn't going to have any effect, because the angry person will just follow them. Getting stadium security to physically remove the other person is more likely to cause a riot than improve the situation.